# Add a key to each value in json array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would like to transform the below JSon. The input JSon array can be of any size. I know its a basic question but I can't find the duplicate.

```
 var input = [{
    "value": 1
 }, {
    "value": 2
 }]

 var output = [{
    "key": {
        "value": 1
    }
 }, {
    "key": {
        "value": 2
    }
 }]
```

Appreciate all the help.

Comment: what are you transforming this json array into? -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this, this should solve your problem

```
output = input.map(value => ({ "key": value }) );
console.log(output);
```

I used ES6 for simplicity, but this does exactly the same.

Comment: you could wrap the object in parens `input.map(value => ({ "key": value }));`

Comment: Right. Thanks :)
Updated the answer now.

Comment: I agree. It is simpler and more complex at the same time, but that is a different discussion altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new array and use `Array#forEach` to push an object with `key = key` and a currently iterated object from `input` as the value.

```js
var input = [{value:1},{value:2}],
    result = [];
    input.forEach(v => result.push({ 'key': v }));
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this will be the most oldschool and hands-on way of doing this.

```js
var input = [{
    "value": 1
 }, {
    "value": 2
 }],
 output = [],
 newItem,
 i = 0, ii = input.length;
 
 
 for(i; i<ii; i++){
  newItem = {};
  newItem.key = {"value":input[i].value};
  output.push(newItem);
 }
 
 console.log(output)
```